# Framer motion animate hide and expand

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, framer-motion

I have this layout, basically 2 columns.
The left column has a hide button as well as a min-width.
When the user clicks "Hide", i would like to animate the left side to go to the left and no be visible. But then I also need the right side to expand to fill in all the space.
The second part of expanding to fill the space I have not been able to do.

I have thrown together a quick sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-tailwind-sidebar-ww23dp?file=/src/App.js

Does anyone know how I could do that?
Whats important is that I would like to have a min-width for the left side too when its visible.